# "integer number too long" Error when my method takes a long (Java)

Tags: java

I have a sorted array of contacts and each object has a Name(string) and phone Number(long). I am using a binary search method that returns the index of the contact with the same number that the user inputs. Even though my Binary search takes a long as parameter, when I call the method, it treats it as an int. So, if I put a number that is greater than the int max limit, I get an error saying that the integer is too long.

I was just testing my code by trying to run the method with a phone number from the array

```
System.out.println(binarySearch(contacts,9077867820,0,1000));
```

And it throws a "integer too large" error. When I try it again with a number that is less than the int max limit like this:

```
System.out.println(contacts[binarySearch(contacts,1171652637,0,1000)]);
```

It returns the index of the contact in the array.

Here is my method:

```
public static int binarySearch(Contact[] A, long key, int low, int high)
{
    int rangeSize = (high-low) + 1;

    int mid = (high+low)/2;
    if(key==A[mid].getNum()) return mid;//found it, no further recursion needed
    else if(rangeSize==1) return -1;//not in array


    if (key<A[mid].getNum()) return binarySearch(A, key, low, mid);
    else return binarySearch(A, key, mid+1, high);        
}
```

Why is it still expecting an int when key is declared as a long?

Answer (score 1):

When you write a number as `123` it is an integer literal. It can only represent numbers in the integer range (`Integer.MIN_VALUE` - `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

To write a long literal, append the `L` suffix: `123L` is a `long` and can represent all numbers in the long range (`Long.MIN_VALUE` - `Long.MAX_VALUE`).

```java
System.out.println(((Object)123).getClass());
System.out.println(((Object)123L).getClass());
```

output:

```
java.lang.Integer
java.lang.Long
```